# how to enable/disable buttons in HTML jscript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to enable buttons on a web page using a js funtion for a django project.
I am new this so please be cool :-)

```js
function change(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  let editID = "edit_".concat(id);
  let deleteID = "delete_".concat(id);

  if (elem.value == "Undo") {
    elem.value = "Modify";
    editButtonElement = document.getElementsByName(editID);
    editButtonElement.disabled = false;

    deleteButtonElement = document.getElementsByName(deleteID);
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = false;
  } else {
    elem.value = "Undo";
    editButtonElement = document.getElementsByName(editID);
    editButtonElement.disabled = true;

    deleteButtonElement = document.getElementsByName(deleteID);
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="11" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_11">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_11">Delete</button>
</div>

<br>

<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="22" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_22">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_22">Delete</button>
</div>

<br>
```

What I would like to happen is for the name of the main button change from `"Modify"` to `"Undo"`, which happens. But I'd also like for the two related `Edit` and `Delete` buttons to be enabled so as to press them.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `getElementsByName` be `getElementById`, since you're passing it an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByName`

```js
function change(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  let editID = "edit_".concat(id)
  let deleteID = "delete_".concat(id)
  if (elem.value == "Undo") {
    elem.value = "Modify";
    editButtonElement = document.getElementById(editID)
    editButtonElement.disabled = false

    deleteButtonElement = document.getElementById(deleteID)
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = false
  } else {
    elem.value = "Undo";
    editButtonElement = document.getElementById(editID)
    editButtonElement.disabled = true

    deleteButtonElement = document.getElementById(deleteID)
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = true
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="11" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_11">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_11">Delete</button>
</div>

<br></br>

<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="22" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_22">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_22">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking "Modify" doesn't do anything, though

Comment: Clicking on Modify actually makes the buttons disabled. I think that is the intended behavior

Comment: I am ashamed... I was focusing so much on the logic (also wrong as pointed out by you guys) that I was getting the elements without the ID...

Comment: @Vineesh The buttons are disabled at start. Unless the UX is backwards, clicking on Modify should obviously enable them. Clicking Undo should disable them again.

Comment: @JeremyThille You are right, but if you see the logic inside the code , when user clicks on `Undo` the below bottons are enabled.  OP may need  to make it enabled by default

Answer (score 2):

You could assign an external event listener to process the buttons clicks using an array of possible states so that a simple toggle mechanism is created.

FYI: `input` elements are `self-closing` so you do not supply a `</input>` as with the majority of HTML tags.

To concatenate in Javascript you use `+` rather than `.` which is the default in PHP so you should change `"edit_".concat(id)` to `"edit_" + id`

```js
const states=['Undo','Modify'];

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]').forEach( bttn=>{
  bttn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.value=states[ 1 - states.indexOf( this.value ) ];
    
    let div=document.querySelector('div.btn-group[data-id="'+this.id+'"]');
        div.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn=>{
          bttn.disabled = this.value==states[1];
        });
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Modify" id="11" class="btn btn-info" />

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" data-id=11>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false">Delete</button>
</div>
<br /><br />

<input type="button" value="Modify" id="22" class="btn btn-info" />

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" data-id=22>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false">Delete</button>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating yourself, you could toggle all buttons in one function. Also you could use a `switch` statement if you want to handle more than "Modify" and "Undo", for instance :

```js
function toggleButtons(id, disabled) {
  ["edit", "delete"].forEach(action => window[`${action}_${id}`].disabled = disabled)
}

function change(id) {

  const elem = window[id],
    v = elem.value;

  switch (v) {
    case "Undo":
      toggleButtons(id, true);
      elem.value = "Modify";
      break;
    default:
      toggleButtons(id, false);
      elem.value = "Undo";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="11" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_11">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_11">Delete</button>
</div>
<br><br>

<input onclick="change(id)" type="button" value="Modify" id="22" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_22">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_22">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is going to work.

```js
function change(id) {

  
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(elem);
  let editID = "edit_".concat(id);
  let deleteID = "delete_".concat(id);

  if (elem.value == "Undo") {
    elem.value = "Modify";
    let editButtonElement = document.getElementById(editID);
    editButtonElement.disabled = false;

    let deleteButtonElement = document.getElementById(deleteID);
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = false;
  } else {
    elem.value = "Undo";
    let editButtonElement = document.getElementById(editID);
    editButtonElement.disabled = true;

    let deleteButtonElement = document.getElementById(deleteID);
    deleteButtonElement.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
  <input onclick="change('eleven')" type="button" value="Modify" id="eleven" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_eleven">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_eleven">Delete</button>
</div>

<br></br>

<input onclick="change('twentyTwo')" type="button" value="Modify" id="twentyTwo" class="btn btn-info"></input>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="edit_twentyTwo">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="false" id="delete_twentyTwo">Delete</button>
</div>
```

you forgot to declare the variables using a keyword like "let" or "var" and used getElementsByName instead of getElementById. It is also a good practice to avoid using numbers as id and to use semicolons. Your code is very clean though

Comment: Thanks!
I also use numbers because I will get several buttons dynamically from django's views.py and I do not know how many rows there will be. hence I have numbers as IDs